# Using UITextField and UIButton to launch a Google search in Safari

Tags: iphone, xcode

I am just finishing up the last part of my app, and I have done something similar before, but I took a pretty long break in coding and forgot.

What I'm trying to do is have the user enter a string in the UITextField and then have that added to a search string and opened in Safari.

Ideas appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Robb - Try this

```
NSString *searchString = @"iPhone"; // UItextField.text
```

NSString *finalString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.google.com/search?q=%@",searchString];

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication]openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:finalString]];
```

this will launch safari with search results of google.

Answer (score 0):

Create the url and open it as a shared application. If you don't want to exit your app then you can probably open the url in a uiwebview.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of this

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urUrlString]];
```